# What is meant by "being at the centre of all the action"?

Tags: phrases, definition

In the context of travelling a city, what does this sentence mean:

> Being at the centre of all the action

It goes something like *"If you stay in a hotel near the Eiffel Tower, you will be at the centre of all the action."*

Comment: It is equivalent to 'The centre of the *activity*', that is, close to all the exciting, interesting, and/or notable events or sites (tourist activities, in this context).

Comment: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/action), def. 19

Comment: @δοῦλος, why don't you answer the question with your comment so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Answered in comments:

> It is equivalent to 'The centre of the activity', that is, close to all the exciting, interesting, and/or notable events or sites (tourist activities, in this context). –  [δοῦλος](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6951/%CE%B4%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82) [Mar 15 2015](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/what-do-you-mean-by-being-at-the-center-of-all-the-action#comment98776_52825)